# Not getting the newest npm package from azure feed

Tags: npm, azure-devops

I made a feed in azure devops and published a npm package to it.

In my client project where I want to use the package I have installed it using "npm i my-package --save-dev", which works.

The package is marked with a caret (^), so that I should get the latest version of that package within that major version.

If I now do "npm clean-install" it won't install the newest version, unlike packages from the npm repository. It looks like it ignores the caret.

In the client package.json it's listed as "my-package": "^1.1.2""
What I get currently is 1.1.6, but there is a 1.1.7 available.

Do I need to setup something for my feed or something else?

Comment: Have you tried use the command line  `npm outdated` to check if that package have newer versions available in the Azure Devops feed? And How about use the command line to install the latest version `$ npm install lodash@latest --save`? https://bytearcher.com/articles/using-npm-update-and-npm-outdated-to-update-dependencies/

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT "npm outdated" will tell me that there is a newer version available (1.1.7). I actually noticed that there are other packages from the npm repo that also doesn't install the latest when using the "npm outdated" command.

I haven't tried "npm install latest", but "npm update my-package" will install the newest. I just didn't think this should be necessary.

Comment: Thanks your reply. Now we could sure that we have the latest version 1.1.7, this issue should be related to how to install the latest version, have you tried my second suggestion above?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT "npm install my-package@latest" also works, but I would prefer not having to run any additional commands. I need to always use the latest package version on our build server, but I guess there is no way around it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: ,How about the workaround add a command line task under the task `npm install`in the build definition with command line `npm install jQuery@latest --save` to force npm install the latest version? Or you still do not want add any additional step to do this?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I already added an update command to the build pipeline, but I'm just puzzled why it's necessary at all.

Comment: to get the reason for this issue, we have to reproduce this issue on my side, but it works fine on my side, if possible, you could provide us a sample to reproduce issue, so that we could investigation it.